# Converting boolean into char equivalent?

Tags: angular, forms

Using `FormGroup`, when you check/uncheck a checkbox in the form, the value is stored as either `true` or `false` in the form object. However, in the database, what I need is either `'y'` or `'n'`.

Is it more appropriate to do the conversion in the server? Or the client?

Comment: This is really subjective. You can probably convert it to y or n right before making the API request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your client code should not be concerned with how the data is stored in the database, so it would be more appropriate to deal with the data conversion on the server, most likely in a data mapper that is called by your server controller.